# XSD to Avro Conversion - SchemaParseException: can't redefine roleNotesGroup

Tags: java, json, xsd, avro

**I am working on converting xsd to avro schema**

XSD snippet:

```
<xsd:element name="roleNotesGroup">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="roleNotesSubGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="roleNotesGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="roleNotes" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xsd:annotation>
                                                <xsd:appinfo>
                                                    <source application="CUSTOMER" field="REL.CUSTOMER"/>
                                                    <fieldPiiAttribute value="INDIRECT"/>
                                                    <fieldPiiPurpose value="LEGITIMATE"/>
                                                    <fieldPiiEraseOption value="NO.ACTION"/>
                                                    <fieldPiiAccessibility value="ACCESS PORTABLE"/>
                                                </xsd:appinfo>
                                            </xsd:annotation>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="index" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="index" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="index" type="xsd:integer"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

I am using

```
Schema schema = Schema.createRecord(name, null, null, false);
```

to create a avro schema record.
In the above xsd roleNotesGroup is a child of roleNotesSubGroup which is a child of roleNotesGroup.
I can recursively obtain the avro schema till roleNotesSubGroup which is then converted to list.

```
List<Schema.Field> is obtained recursively.
```

Now the problem is when i try to add the Fields formed to the head element roleNotesGroup using

```
Schema schema = Schema.createRecord(name, null, null, false);
schema.setFields(schemaFields);
```

I get the following error :
SchemaParseException: can't redefine roleNotesGroup

**Is there any restriction in avro or avro conversion that the same names should not occur again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from apache jira.
The solution would be to use a different namespace ( suggested by apache ) for that recurring elements or using aliases ( works for me ).

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2809